# How to evaluate an expression in Access like evaluating a formula in excel

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

Is there a way to evaluate an expression in Access like we can evaluate formulae in Excel? My Dlookup keeps resulting in the number two and I can't figure out where the hang up is.

```
=Nz(DLookUp("[RemanChangePoint]![ID]","[RemanChangePoint]","[NewPartNum]  Like '*" & [LegacyPN1] & "*' Or [NewPartNum] Like '*" & [LegacyPN2] & "*'"),"")
```

There's 10 more LegacyPNs and I am expecting to get either the ID of the record that has the LegacyPN or a blank. Before, instead of doing it as above, I was doing:

```
Like & Chr(34) & "*" & [LegacyPN#] & "*" & Chr(34) & " Or..."
```

It would result in 2 every time. But now with the shortened version, it's resulting in blanks every time, even though there are records with the part number.

I have a similar expression on a different form, but only one LegacyPN to use as the lookup so it works. I assume that the problem is the numerous Or statements, but it doesn't make sense to me why it's not working, thus the desire for an expression evaluator like Excel has.

Or (and this may be a little uncouth to ask a slightly different question)

Is there a way to use an attachment's file name as the criteria for Dlookup? That may prove more effective than going by LegacyPN, I just can't figure it out via the expression builder.

Comment: post your actual code and problem and expected result :)

Comment: Edited with the code and expectation.

Comment: See nothing wrong with syntax as long as the fields in the criteria are all text type and all have data. It works for me. DLookup() returns first value it encounters that meets the criteria. If the first LIKE is matched, the second is ignored. Nulls will return erroneous result.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to reference an attachment field FileName property in a DLookup().

Comment: Thanks @June7. Most likely the part number needed will be in the first 4 (probably first or second really) likes, so ignoring the rest shouldn't be a problem; actually preferred even.

Comment: I started messing around with the attachment field stuff, but stopped short of writing a DLookup because some of the records have multiple attachments and the form would then cycle through each name (so a record with 9 attachments would pop up as nine different records when navigating). I didn't like that so trying to find an alternate alternative. I was having an off day when I asked this so hopefully I can do it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first DLookup where clause is referring to fields on the current form since the double quotes cause the expression to break out of the where clause and into the scope of the ControlSource.

This means something like the following will be passed into the DLookup function because the [LegacyPN] portions of the expression are evaluated in the context of the form, before DLookup is called:

```
[NewPartNum]  Like '*1*' Or [NewPartNum] Like '*2*'
```

...where 1 and 2 are values of [LegacyPN1] and [LegacyPN2] on the current form.

If you want the [LegacyPN] fields in the DLookup where clause to refer to the [RemanChangePoint] table being queried by the DLookup, then you need to fix your quotes:

```
=Nz(DLookUp("[RemanChangePoint]![ID]","[RemanChangePoint]", "[NewPartNum]  Like '*' & [LegacyPN1] & '*' Or [NewPartNum] Like '*' & [LegacyPN2] & '*'"),"")
```

Your second syntax should have also worked because the Chr(34) added a double quote resulting in this final string being passed to the DLookup function in the where clause:

```
Like & "*" & [LegacyPN] & "*" & " Or..."
```

In which the [LegacyPN] field refers to the table within the DLookup query, not the current form. So I'm not sure why that didn't work. Note: single quotes or double quotes work okay in this context but not a mixture.

Double quotes get tricky within arguments of functions within a CountrolSource property (and other places).

Comment: Thanks. This worked. I never would have thought to wrap the asterisks in single quotes. Personally I am not a fan of the expression builder. I'd rather do it through vba, but I don't want to deal with event triggers for this particular feature. Now I just need to tweak things because I'll have multiple instances of a part number in the table the form is bound to but only one (usually) for RemanChangePoint. But that's for another time... Thanks again!